# Move by offset of web elements in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I actually want to move by offset for about 100 elements, by 72 px downwards

my code:

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        while True:
        actions.pause(2.5)
        actions.move_by_offset(0, 72)
        actions.pause(4.2)
        actions.perform()
```

**Problem:**
Its that when i move by offset once in the while loop, then it goes back to 0,0, thus moving back to the 0 px element

**How can i move by offset or you say hover onto element by 72 px down, and not make it go back to 0,0**

And it works fine, when i type manually it many times, but this method is a bad practice:

```
while True:
        actions.pause(2.5)
        actions.move_by_offset(0, 72)
        actions.move_by_offset(0, 72)
        actions.move_by_offset(0, 72)
        actions.pause(4.2)
        actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with Selenium. A simple solution is to uninstall stable version and install alpha/beta version. That solved the issue for me!

```
pip uninstall selenium

pip install --pre selenium
```